# what is the use/meaning of taking the partial derivatives of a joint distribution?

Tags: sampling, gradient-descent, joint-distribution, hierarchical-bayesian, derivative

This is probably too broad, but is worth asking: Assuming an unknown distribution (from which you would like to sample), is there any benefit in looking at the gradients of the joint with respect to each parameter? What does each partial derivative even mean?

The reason I am looking at this is to somehow use the derivatives to initialize the Gibbs sampler of those parameters properly. I was hoping to somehow move close to the high density area of the distribution and initialize the parameters accordingly (a bit of warm start for the sampler), instead of randomly initializing them. But I have no idea if this even makes sense.

Comment: Initializing near a high-density region can definitely make sense, especially if you're going to be tuning some of the sampler's parameters; you want the sampler to be tuned to do well in high-density regions. With regard to the partial derivatives, they are used extensively in Hamiltonian Monte Carlo, but I'm not sure that they have much of a probabilistic interpretation.

Comment: Typically the use of partial derivatives would be looking for modes. For example maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: @DavidJ.Harris have you seen any work (paper, report, etc) that makes use of derivatives in initializing the sampler?

Comment: @user3639557 This FAQ mentions starting at the mode of a distribution near the bottom of the page (as GeoMatt suggested). Most of the best ways to find the a mode involve gradients (i.e. vectors of partial derivatives). http://users.stat.umn.edu/~geyer/mcmc/burn.html#other